# Python - Match string between { } characters, but not between {{ }}

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I'm trying to match some variable names in a html document to populate a dictionary. I have the html

```
<div class="no_float">
    <b>{node_A_test00:02d}</b>{{css}}
    <br />
    Block mask: {block_mask_lower_node_A} to {block_mask_upper_node_A}
    <br />
</div>
<div class="sw_sel_container">
    Switch selections: 
    <table class="sw_sel">
        <tr>
            <td class="{sw_sel_node_A_03}">1</td>
            <td class="{sw_sel_node_A_03}">2</td>
            <td class="{sw_sel_node_A_03}">3</td>
            <td class="{sw_sel_node_A_04}">4</td>
            <td class="{sw_sel_node_A_05}">5</td>
```

I want to match code between { and ( } or : ). But if it starts with {{ I don't want to match it at all (I will be using this for inline css}

so far I have the regex expression

```
(?<=\{)((?!{).*?)(?=\}|:)
```

but this is still matching text inside {{css}}.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Well... this isn't exactly parsing HTML since the OP isn't trying to do anything with tags.

Comment: @F.J True. But it's kind of obligatory to post that link everywhere HTML and Regex are mentioned in the same question, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you've already found a solution that works, but I thought it might be worthwhile to explain what the problem with your original regex is.

- `(?<=\{)` means that a `{` must precede whatever matches next. Fair enough.
- `((?!{).*?)` will match anything that starts with a character other than `{`. Okay, so we're only matching things *inside* the braces. Good.

But now consider what happens when you have two opening braces: `{{bar}}`. Consider the substring `bar`. What precedes the `b`? A `{`. Does `bar` start with `{`? Nope. So the regex will consider this a match.

You have, of course, prevented the regex from matching `{bar}`, which is what it would do if you left the `(?!{)` out of your pattern, because `{bar}` starts with a `{`. But as soon as the regex engine determines that no valid match starts on the `{` character, it moves on to the next character--`b`--and sees that a match starts there.

Now, just for kicks, here's the regex I'd use:

`(?!<={){([^{}:]+)[}:](?!=})`

- `(?!<{)` : the match shouldn't be preceded by `{`.
- `{` : the match starts with an open brace.
- `([^{}:]+)` : **group** everything that isn't an open-brace, close-brace, or colon. This is the part of the match that we actually want.
- `[}:]` : end the match with a close-brace or colon.
- `(?!})` : the match shouldn't be followed by `}`.

Comment: Thank for explaining that @Kyle. That makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: @user2341223 You're welcome! If you find answers helpful, please consider [upvoting and/or accepting them](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
re.findall(r'''
    (?<!\{)    # No opening bracket before
    \{         # Opening bracket
      ([^}]+)  # Stuff inside brackets
    \}         # Closing bracket
    (?!\})     # No closing bracket after
''', '{foo} {{bar}} {foo}', flags=re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Blender, thats works. I also found that because i'm using curly braces I can use string.Formatter() and parse out the field_names

Comment: Wouldn't this match {{bar}, though? Granted, that's only a problem if brackets are unmatched.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

```
(?<=(?<!{){)[^{}:]+
```

and this with a capture:

```
(?<!{){([^{}:]+)
```